# Play videos on a streaming mini window at the bottom of ios screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

DraggableYoutubeFloatingVideo allows you to play videos on a floating mini window at the bottom of your screen from sites like YouTube,facebook.

so same as like youtube floating video. please any one share demo app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: [DraggableYoutubeFloatingVideo](https://github.com/vizllx/DraggableYoutubeFloatingVideo)